# C++\CLI .Net Dictionary -> std::map

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Здравствуйте, ситуация такова :
имеется dll на С# и конкретный метод с вот такой сигнатурой :

```
bool IsStart(Dictionary<String,String> seetings)
```

Нужно вызвать этот метод в проекте на Delphi.Поскольку напрямую это не сделать, есть оболочка на 
С++ CLR, в которой данный метод имеет следующий вид :

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool IsStart(Dictionary<String^,String^>^ settings) 
{
    return \Class_name\::IsStart(settings);
}
```

Насколько я правильно понимаю  указание extern "C" требует, чтобы параметры данной функции были совместимы именно с нативным С . И вместо `Dictionary<String^,String^>^`
 нужен аналогичный контейнер на С( но если убрать `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)` все компилируется ). Пытался передавать map, но конечно же компилятор ругается , наверное из-за того,что сама оболочка на управляемом С написана.Но даже если я передам в эту функцию верный параметр , потом как-то данный С совместимый контейнер надо будет маршалировать в `Dictionary<String^,String^>^` чтобы передать в метод.Если кто-то что-нибудь посоветует,буду крайне признателен.

Comment: На чистом C вообще нет контейнеров, вам придётся писать структуру данных самостоятельно. В std::map смаршалировать можно, конечно, но это не скомпилируется с `extern "C"`.

Comment: Точно,забыл про это.Спасибо.Придется вспоминать С.

Comment: Не за что, это вряд ли решает вашу проблему.

Comment: Возможно, легче всего использовать [COM Interop](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32754): экспортировать класс на C# как COM-объект, и подключить этот COM-объект к Delphi.

Comment: К сожалению проект уже реализован(помимо необходимого метода, куча сторонних, написанных не мной) и я лишь могу довольствоваться существующей архитектурой.

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports